# C++ Windows Forms:: Get TabControl Instance from Control (or from anywhere else, if possible)?

Tags: c++, winforms, tabs

I have a **TabControl** in my Form and a few tools that enable the user to add new tabs in runtime, to delete them, to rename them and to save the whole thing. Of course, starting the program again will load the Tabs again. Each tab also contains a TextBox which will also be saved and loaded.
The next thing I wanted to add was the option to add **a tab which contains other tabs**.

So basically, I create a **TabPage** which doesn't contain a TextBox like the other tabs do, but instead **contains another TabControl**.
At the Time of creation I add one "SubTab" inside the **"SubTabControl"**, but I want to be able to access this TabControl later and add more Tabs to it.

This has been really difficult for me. Any suggestions on how I can **create a variable amount of TabControls and still be able to access them individually** (to access each of their tabs)? I tried  arrays but I couldn't get it to work and I also tried using *GetNextControl* to return the TabControl as a *Control-Type object*. This worked up to the point where I wanted to add more Tabs. Unfortunately, the returned object was of type *Control*, so I couldnt use the functions limited to *TabControl*.

Comment: Learn how to use safe_cast<>.

Comment: I didn't even expect an answer with so many new questions posted every minute. Thanks to you, I figured out a solution:

    `if (refControl->GetType() == tabControl1->GetType())
   {
     TabControl ^refTabControl = safe_cast<TabControl ^>(refControl); .... }`